# Appropriate loader webpack for js libary with vueJs 3.0.0

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, vuejs3, babeljs

I work on an Vue 3.0.0 projekt which a coworker created. The Problem is if i try to install additional libraries and use it I get the error.

> in ./node_modules/qalendar/dist/qalendar.es.js
>
> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5019:154)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> if (!t || !this.isVisible)
> return;
>
> const n = !t.contains(e.target), a = !!e.target.closest(".is-event"), r = ((s = this.config.eventDialog) == null ? void 0 : s.closeOnClickOutside) ?? !0;
>
> this.isVisible && n && !a && r && this.closeFlyout();
> |     }
>
> @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--1-1!./src/components/kalender.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js 1:0-36 4:4-12
> @ ./src/components/kalender.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js
> @ ./src/components/kalender.vue
> @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--15-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/ts-loader??ref--15-2!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--1-1!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts
> @ ./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts
> @ ./src/App.vue
> @ ./src/main.ts
> multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://10.1.27.3:8481&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.ts

I tried two libraries and just used their default Component configuration
https://vcalendar.io/
https://tomosterlund.github.io/qalendar/guide.html#installing

I think it has something to do with the ES2020 features in the library so i tried updating my dependencies but it didn´t help

Old

> "dependencies": {     "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",     "@vueform/multiselect": "^2.3.2",     "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",     "bootstrap-icons": "^1.8.1",     "core-js": "^3.6.5",     "dayjs": "^1.11.5",     "vue": "^3.0.0",     "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.6",     "vue3-loading-overlay": "^0.0.0",     "vuex": "^4.0.2"   },   "devDependencies": {     "@types/bootstrap": "^5.2.3",     "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.18.0",     "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.18.0",     "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",     "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",     "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.15",     "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",     "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",     "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^7.0.0",     "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",     "eslint": "^6.7.2",     "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",     "typescript": "~4.1.5"   },

Updated

> "dependencies": {     "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",     "@vueform/multiselect": "^2.6.2",     "bootstrap": "^5.3.0",     "bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.5",     "core-js": "^3.31.1",     "dayjs": "^1.11.9",     "qalendar": "^3.5.0",     "vue": "^3.3.4",     "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.7",     "vue3-loading-overlay": "^0.0.0",     "vuex": "^4.1.0"   },   "devDependencies": {     "@types/bootstrap": "^5.2.6",     "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.33.0",     "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.33.0",     "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",     "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",     "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.15",     "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",     "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.3.4",     "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^7.0.0",     "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",     "eslint": "^6.8.0",     "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.20.0",     "typescript": "~4.1.5"   },

babel.config.js
`module.exports = {   presets: [     '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'   ] }`

I tried to update the dependencies and looked into babel/Webpack ES2020 but I didn´t find anything

Comment: By looking at your package.json I came to know that you first installed "qalendar": "^3.5.0",  and observed an issue while using that component then I think you executed "npm install" so all dependencies and dev dependencies are upgraded to the latest versions. I suggest never upgrading all dependencies and dev dependencies at once.  Can you provide a package-lock.json fiel before updating complete packages?

Comment: https://github.com/PrivacyStatement/Share/blob/main/package-lock.json